# How can a Buffalo Plaid Texture be achieved with Image Textures with Blender Internal Renderer ?

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, procedural

[image]

I got a couple of great answers to another question about Buffalo Plaid Texture with Cycles Render. But I am curious if it can be done with Blender Internal Renderer, and also, if instead of colors with color ramp, we could plug in images. Three images, one for the dark color, another for light, and a third one, which typically would be created by mixing the first two color via stripes or color mixing.

Comment: I want to use watercolor textures instead of solid colors to be precise.

Comment: To use it in Blender Render engine you can Bake procedural texture in Cycle and use it as Image Texture. You want to change colors to images in Cycles or BR?

Comment: For this purpose specifically, I want to avoid using cycles completely. Actually, I am going to use shadeless materials for combining images into these textures.